# What is returned by the call wacky 4,6? also how to calculate this recursion?

Tags: java, recursion

```
    public static int wacky (int x , int y){
     if(x <= 1){
      return y;
    }
    else{
         return wacky(x - 1, y - 1) + y;
        }
    }
```

I had a test a while but I still don't know how to do a recursion step by step and I remember this question by memory and I guess on the test thinking that you maybe calculate this way...
public static = 4 + 6 + 1 + 4 + 4 - 1 + 6 - 1 + 6
but was not of the answer choice I realize i was doing something wrong...
my teacher doesn't help me and don't even care I try to get help but he does not how to explain this...

Comment: Have you tried writing every single call on paper to go through the execution yourself? How about a line-by-line step through in the debugger?

Comment: No_____________

Comment: Then you should?

Comment: I have tried to add code that was missing though

Comment: class bb{
     public static int wacky (int x , int y){
     if(x <= 1){
      return y;
    }
    else{
         return wacky(x - 1, y - 1) + y;
        }
    }
}

Comment: Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call a function recursively, they add the new function to a stack until have a final result (`return`). When it occurs, you go back return by return in the stack.

An Execution example:

First Round `wacky(4, 6)`:

- `4 <= 1`? No, so call `wacky(4 - 1, 6 - 1)`

  Second Round `wacky(3, 5)`:

  - `3 <= 1`? No, so call `wacky(3 - 1, 5 - 1)`

    Third Round `wacky(2, 4)`:

    - `2 <= 1`? No, so call `wacky(2 - 1, 4 - 1)`

      Fourth Round `wacky(1, 3)`:

      - `1 <= 1`? Yes
      - return 3;
    - `return 3 + 4`;
  - `return 3 + 4 + 5`;
- `return 3 + 4 + 5 + 6`;

Answer (score 0):

Why not let Java tell you what is going on? Insert some `print` statements so you can see the values when the code runs:

```
private static int indent = 1;
public static int wacky(int x , int y) {
    System.out.printf("%" + (indent++ * 2) + "swacky(%d, %d)%n", "", x, y);
    int result;
    if (x <= 1)
        result = y;
    else
        result = wacky(x - 1, y - 1) + y;
    System.out.printf("%" + (indent-- * 2) + "s-> %d%n", "", result);
    return result;
}
```

*Test*

```
wacky(4, 6);
```

*Output*

```
  wacky(4, 6)
    wacky(3, 5)
      wacky(2, 4)
        wacky(1, 3)
          -> 3
        -> 7
      -> 12
    -> 18
```